# I am creating a Library program. How should I transfer books?

Tags: java, object, memory, data-transfer

In my program a collection of "Book" objects is held by a "Shelf" object, which a series of are held by a "Library" object.

Each "Shelf" holds a certain amount of books. Currently, I have a "Reference" book to identify the Book the shelf can hold. Each "Shelf" has an ArrayList of copies of the same book that refer to unique objects identical to the "Reference" book.

When I transfer a book in the shelf to a user, should I transfer an entire instance of the "Book" and its reference variable and delete the reference variable to that instance from the shelf?

Or...

Should I keep track of the amount of books left with an int variable and simply make copies of the reference variable to the "Reference" book to the user?

In an essence...

Liberal memory use vs. Conservative

Physical transfer vs. Conceptual

respectively.

Comment: Copy the reference variable, and delete the old reference variable.  Don't move the book at all in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably library books have a fixed place on a shelf?

In which case I would simply mark a book as checked out and record the date when the book is due back and a reference to the user who checked it out.

On the user side, they can have a `List` of books that they have currently checked out. This is a one-to-many relationship.

This way when the user checks the books back in you just need to flip some flags, you do not need to search for where the book "goes" on the shelf.

If you are trying to *model* a library however then the former approach would seem more applicable...

Comment: Alright. I believe the latter would be much easier to write. However, I like the idea of modeling a library. But to do so seems excessive. Its just that modeling a library seems more concrete than the former.